# Change transparacy of an image created thanks to a function

Tags: python, pygame

I'm displaying two random images in my pygame project that need to change when pressing one "z" or "x" in my keyboard. So I've created a function to do so and the images are correctly showing and changing. My problem is with the if statement in the run function: when the condition are met the sound start playing, but the images don't change their transparency. This is my code:

```
class Main():
    def __init__(self): 
        pygame.init()


        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.sound_one = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join("soundone.mp3"))
        self.sound_two = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join("soundtwo.mp3"))

        self.image_list = [] # a list with all the images       
        
            
    def show_image(self, image_one, image_two):
        rect_one = image_one.get_rect(midleft=(50, 240))
        rect_two = image_two.get_rect(midright=(640- 50, 240))

        image_one.set_alpha(0)
        image_two.set_alpha(0)      

        self.window.blit(image_one, rect_one)
        self.window.blit(image_two, rect_two)
        
        pygame.display.update()

        return image_one, image_two


    def run(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_z:
                        self.one, self.two = self.show_image(random.choice(self.image_list), random.choice(self.image_list))
                    if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                        self.one, self.two = self.show_image(random.choice(self.image_list), random.choice(self.image_list))

            self.window.fill((0,0,0))

            if self.value <= 42:
                self.one.set_alpha(50)
                self.two.set_alpha(0)
                self.sound_two.play(loops=0)
                
            elif self.value > 53:
                self.sound_one.play(loops=0)
                self.one.set_alpha(0)
                self.two.set_alpha(50)
                
            elif 42 > self.value > 53:
                self.one.set_alpha(0)
                self.two.set_alpha(0)

        self.clock.tick(30)                     


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.run()
```

How can I access the image created with a function to edit it? My code is not giving me back any error. It just doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You have to redraw the scene in every frame You must draw the images in the application loop and update the display in every frame:

```py
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = True   
            if event.key == pygame.K_z:
                self.one, self.two = random.choice(self.image_list), random.choice(self.image_list)
            if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                self.one, self.two = random.choice(self.image_list), random.choice(self.image_list)

    self.window.fill((0,0,0))
    rect_one = image_one.get_rect(midleft=(50, 240))
    rect_two = image_two.get_rect(midright=(640- 50, 240))
    self.window.blit(self.one, rect_one)
    self.window.blit(self.two, rect_two)
    pygame.display.update()

    # [...]

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)